# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: magento2, error

When I trying to open my magento2 live site it showing error

[www.store.vidya.sg](http://www.store.vidya.sg)

> redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS".

I have clear the browser catch and cookies. But still not open.

Admin panel also not open.

Comment: It works for me fine. Where are you facing issue ?

Comment: Is https is enabled in magento without having SSL certificates?

Comment: **Success solution !!** [ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331650/80247) it saved my time.

Comment: **This answer saved my time and life !** [Solution ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331650/94721)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your PHPMyAdmin from your host try once this SQL command.

**Run this SQL:**

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
UPDATE core_store SET store_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE core_store_group SET group_id = 0 WHERE name='Default';
UPDATE core_website SET website_id = 0 WHERE code='admin';
UPDATE customer_group SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```