# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS magento admin

Tags: magento2, 301-redirect, magento-admin, magento-install

[image]
After enable https, magento store works as expected but magento admin dashboard gives this error.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem Solved !**

I have tried many solutions, but none of them work. Finally, **I figured out a successful solution**.

**Step one,**

Check your proxy server configuration, In my scenario I used **nginx** as proxy server.

```
server {
    server_name demoo.magento.xyz; ##replace your domain 

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; ##replce your local address and port
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
    }

listen 443 ssl http2;
##Do not add these lines, below lines will add after Obtaining an SSL Certificate##
ssl_certificate /xxx.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /xxx.pem;
include /path_to/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
ssl_dhparam /path_to/ssl-dhparams.pem;
```

}

**Step two,**

Check your config in db table called **core_config_data**. usel below command in sql cli.

**select * from core_congif_data;** and data should be like this,

- web/seo/use_rewrites -> 1
- web/unsecure/base_url -> http://demoo.magento.xyz/ ##replace your address
- web/unsecure/base_link_url -> http://demoo.magento.xyz/
- web/secure/base_url -> https://demoo.magento.xyz/
- web/secure/base_link_url - https://demoo.magento.xyz/
- web/secure/use_in_frontend -> 1
- web/secure/use_in_adminhtml -> 1
- web/cookie/cookie_domain -> null
- web/cookie/cookie_httponly -> null
- web/cookie/cookie_path -> null
- web/secure/base_static_url -> null
- web/secure/base_media_url -> null
- web/secure/enable_hsts -> 0
- web/secure/enable_upgrade_insecure -> 0

**Final step,**

- Clean cache **php bin/magento cache:clean**
- Setup upgrade **bin/magento setup:upgrade**
- deploy static files **bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**
- Clear browser cache

**Congratulations! Now your admin should work properly.**

Comment: please consider marking your answer as solution to your question so others can see it too. cheers!

Comment: @DianaBotean updated! thankyou.

Comment: can you also mark your answer as accepted solution?

Comment: @DianaBotean  yes, I can suggest this is an "accepted solution" ,but i don't have any privilege to mark it. thank you.

Comment: oh ok, sorry about that :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Harsha Liyadipita. this answer worked for me!

[magento admin ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331650/94721)

Comment: glad to hear that @lawemi.

Answer (score 0):

If the database modifications don't fix the problem, the web server may be to blame. I fixed this problem by adding "**fastcgi_param HTTPS on;**" to my  nginx fastcgi_params configuration.